# Does $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n}{n + \sum_{k=1}^{n}k}$ converge to $0$ or $1$?

Tags: calculus, limits, summation

Clearly this converges. I am asking whether it converges to $0$ or $1$ because both seem to make sense. Using LH, the sum becomes
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n}{n + \sum_{k=1}^{n}k}\Rightarrow _{LH}\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{1+0}=1$$
However I believe I am making a mistake because my idea is that since $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k$ is always a constant, I can differentiate term by term in terms of $d/dn$ to get $0$, but $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k$ is in terms of $k$. The case that this converges to $0$ is strong since $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k > n$ for all $n>1$, as in the denominator grows much faster than the numerator. Nonetheless, I want a solid understanding on why I cannot differentiate the sum term by term in terms of $d/dn$ and thus not use LH. Furthermore I suspect that we can just convert $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k$ to its sequence of partial sums which would be in terms of $n$ and then evaluate the limit from there, but I got lost trying to do this.

Comment: If we should talk about some kind of derivative of $\sum_{k=1}^{n}$ with respect to $n$ then the derivative would be $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} - \sum_{k=1}^{n} = n+1$, not $0$.

Comment: The use of  l'Hôpital's rule  makes no sense here, but you can use the Stolz–Cesàro theorem theorem with sequences $(n)$ and $\left(n+\sum_{k=1}^n k\right)$.  ***However***, if you instead write $n+\sum_{k=1}^nk=n+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\frac{n(n+3)}{2}$, then the denominator and the numerator can be seen as differentiable functions on $n$, and you can apply l'Hôpital's rule in this situation.

Comment: Thank you both very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write 
$$
\frac{n}{n+\sum_{k=1}^nk}=\frac1{1+\frac1n\,\sum_{k=1}^nk}.
$$
Now, 
$$
\frac1n\,\sum_{k=1}^nk=\frac1n\,\frac{n(n+1)}2=\frac{n+1}2. 
$$
Thus
$$
\frac{n}{n+\sum_{k=1}^nk}=\frac1{1+\frac{n+1}2}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0.
$$

It doesn't make sense to apply L'Hôpital, as you don't have functions over the real line, just discrete functions. In particular you cannot define the sum for all $x$.

Answer (score 0):

hint:  $ 0 < a_n < \dfrac{2}{n} $ with $a_n$ is the expression you need to find the limit.

Comment: Where did you get $\frac{2}{n}$ from?